# TERRAFORM gcloud instance snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a gcloud instance snapshot (you can view it in the screenshot (ls-snapshot.png)).

[image: google cloud sanpshot]

I want to import it and use it in a google_compute_instance like the code below.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "servers" {
    count = var.count_server
    name = "server-${count.index + 1}"
    machine_type = "-------"
    zone = "--------"
    allow_stopping_for_update = "true"
    tags = [ "server",  "private-access" ]
    labels = {
        "name" = "server-${count.index + 1}"
        "type" = "server"
    }
    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = var.ubuntu_2004_sku
        }
    }
    network_interface {
        network = var.vpc_name
        subnetwork = var.vpc_subnet_private_name
        network_ip = "0.0.0.${count.index + 2}"
    }
    service_account {
        scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro", "cloud-platform"]
        email = "terraform-sa@---------.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
}
```

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [terraform import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import) command:

```
terraform import 'google_compute_instance.servers[0]' <id-of-the-instance>
```

You have to do it manually for all instances, so next one would be:

```
terraform import 'google_compute_instance.servers[1]' <id-of-the-instance>
```

and so on.

Comment: I want to implement the snapshot on the servers I create with that code I just don't know how to import the snapshot and implemented into that resource

Comment: @BernardoRebelo You question is about importing `google_compute_instance`, not snapshots. Thus, please make new question relevant to that new issue with snapshots with corresponding details and info.

Comment: " snapshot (you can view it in the annexed file (ls-snapshot.png), I want to import it and use it in a google_compute_instance", is literally at the beginning of the text what I'm asking for. No need to make a new question. If you think I should alter the text please make a suggestion.